# How to GROUP BY with NULL values in dynamic pivot

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

This is my query sample:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##A') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##A
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#table1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #table1

Create table #Table1 ( ControlNo INT, Line varchar(50), Profit INT, Code varchar(50) )

INSERT INTO #Table1 (ControlNo, Line, Profit, Code) 
    VALUES  (1111,'Line1',NULL,NULL), 
            (1111,'Line2',100,'A'), 
            (3333,'Line1',200,'C'), 
            (4444,'Line1',50,'B'), 
            (4444,'Line2',100,NULL)
DECLARE @columns AS NVARCHAR(MAX), 
        @finalquery AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @columns = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Line) FROM #Table1 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')

set @finalquery = '
        select  p.ControlNo,
                p.Code,' + @columns + '
        from ( select ControlNo, Line, Code, Profit
                from #Table1
            )a 
    pivot 
    ( 
     SUM(Profit) 
     for Line IN (' + @columns + ') 
    )p 
    ORDER BY ControlNo
    '
exec(@finalquery)
```

Outcome has rows with `NULL`'s in it.

```
ControlNo   Code    Line1   Line2
 1111       NULL    NULL    NULL
 1111        A      NULL    100
 3333        C      200    NULL
 4444       NULL    NULL    100
 4444        B       50     NULL
```

The desired output needs to be like this:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand: how does the row code = B land up with Line2 = 100, if it's from `4444       NULL    NULL    100` that doesn't have a code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like regular conditional aggregation would work better here, because `Code` appears to be just `MIN(Code)` per `ControlNo`

```
DECLARE @columns nvarchar(max) =
  STUFF((SELECT distinct
        ',ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Line = ' + QUOTENAME(Line, '''') + ' THEN Profit END), 0) ' + QUOTENAME(Line)
        FROM #Table1
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('text()[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1 , LEN(','),'');

DECLARE @finalquery nvarchar(max)= N'
SELECT
  t.ControlNo,
  MIN(t.Code) Code,
  ' + @columns + '
from #Table1 t
GROUP BY
  t.ControlNo
ORDER BY ControlNo;
';
    
PRINT @finalquery; -- for testing

EXEC sp_executesql
  @finalquery;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7a8b66b670075e6483b0db79c705bd54)